Gemini does not work in server application
Locally works fine and in the server not. It's not be cause of the local of the server (Germany) because I tested the Gemini request Curl in the terminal and worked.
This is the log of this package
Server is running on port 3000 
/app/node_modules/@google/generative-ai/dist/index.js:353
            throw new GoogleGenerativeAIFetchError(`Error fetching from ${url.toString()}: [${response.status} ${response.statusText}] ${message}`, response.status, response.statusText, errorDetails);
                  ^

GoogleGenerativeAIFetchError: [GoogleGenerativeAI Error]: Error fetching from https://generativelanguage.googleapis.com/v1beta/models/gemini-1.5-flash:generateContent: [403 Forbidden] 
    at _makeRequestInternal (/app/node_modules/@google/generative-ai/dist/index.js:353:19)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async generateCon
```tent (/app/node_modules/@google/generative-ai/dist/index.js:752:22) {
  status: 403,
  statusText: 'Forbidden',
  errorDetails: undefined
}

Node.js v18.20.2
The response of the raw request is this:
<title>Error 403 (Forbidden)!!1</title>
<p><b>403.</b> <ins>That’s an error.</ins></p>
<p>Your client does not have permission to get URL <code>/v1beta/models/gemini-1.5-flash:generateContent</code> from this server. <ins>That’s all we know.</ins></p>

My instance (working fine locally):
const aiModel = genAI.getGenerativeModel({
  model: 'gemini-1.5-flash',
  systemInstruction: CHAT_GPT_SYSTEM_PROMPT_MESSAGE,
});

No idea what is going on, I've been for a while on this.
